# Show error message conditionally in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to fix a problem in jQuery today, and I'm not getting it right.. I want to show an error when uploading of a file failed, but the api Im using is not going further because of the backend.. long story short: I only have the success call to work with.

It now shows the error, even when the upload was successful and I am unable to wrap my head around it. It is because the error is in the timeout.

I only want to show the error when the call failed, but unfortunately we don't have that option. So the only option is to always show the error unless the call is successful. But because the error message is in the timeout, it will pop up even when the upload was successful.

Here's my beautiful jQuery so far:

```
function upload () {
    hideErrorMessages(); // hiding the errors when user clicks upload
    api.captureAndProcessImage(captureFrontCallback, params, function () {
        spinner(); // call this function which is a spinner
    })
}
```

This is the spinner that I have so far:

```
    function spinner () {
    $('body').waitMe({
        effect: 'bounce',
        text: 'Uploading'
    })

    setTimeout(function(){
        stopUploading(); 
        showErrorMessage('something went wrong');
    }, 1500)
}
```

And here is the stop uploading function, to stop the uploading (because the api is stuck and won't return a failure or anything:

```
    function stopUploading () {
    $('body').waitMe('hide');
}
```

The showErrorMessage function just prints a div to the DOM with the error.

Now the success function:

```
function captureImage (result) {
    if (result.status === 'success') {
        hideErrorMessage();
        // theres some more stuff here like putting in a trash bin etc
    } else { 
      // this never gets reached because it is stuck in uploading
}
```

The problem you see is that the error message is always shown, even when the result is successful, because it is in the time out... Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is working as designed.

This isn't a jQuery issue, it's a problem with your API not returning the data you need.

Either the API needs to return an error code instead of a 200 OK when it fails , or it needs to return the upload status in the response.

The only alternative would be to attempt to access the file after the upload process and listen for a 404 - but this method is far from ideal and may have security implications.

Comment: Yes, I cant even do if not successfull, I tried to console log but it's either successfull or stuck in uploading..

Comment: If it's timeouts that are the only cause of it failing, then you can apply your setTimeout to a variable and then clear it on success

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

instead of just using : 

    setTimeout(function(){
    ...
    }

You need to use : 

    var uploadFailTimeout;
    uploadFailTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
     // show error message
    }

then change your success handler to :

    if(result.status =='success'){
    clearTimeout(uploadFileTimeout);
    }